Are the chidren of muslim couple default muslims?
One of the brothers who runs a blog called fussilat supposedly admits that covenant 7:172 is a form of testimony of faith.
Can this be taken as a basic testimony to assume the new borns irrespective of their parents religion be considered muslims.
Hence the wider question, the testimony of faith is only affirmation of BELIEF IN HEART (Quran 49:14) and the person is a muslim with Allah and ultimately prove that chidren of muslim parents are also muslims without saying and understanding the wording of popular testimony?

assalamu alaikom
Children born to Muslim parentsare considered Muslim, regardless of whether they have consciously declared the Shahada or not.
The ruling comes from the hadith of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), who said:
"Every child is born upon fitrah (natural disposition). It is his parents who make him a Jew, a Christian, or a Magian."
(Sahih al-Bukhari)
